# Laravel route links inside Vue.js component?

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-component

What is the best approach to generate Laravel route links inside Vue component?

So I see two approaches, either generate them in view, with Laravel's route functions (link_to_route(), etc...), and just pass them as component properties.

Or well just hard code them, inside the template (seems like the worse option of the 2).

Is there any other approach I could take? As both of these, feels kinda hacky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this package:

https://github.com/aaronlord/laroute

It builds all the js routes from your laravel route files using an artisan command

```
php artisan laroute:generate
```

Then it provides js versions of the laravel route helper functions.

Comment: oh thats interesting, will definitely check it out. Thanks! :)